# how to couple a python code with a SWAT watershed model

Tags: python, model, fortran, geospatial

I'm taking a shot in the dark that someone can guide me with this.  I've just started working on this and information is not so easy to find.  I have a python code that simulates land use change and can output arcgis raster images.  The watershed model SWAT uses these images to calculate land use parameters generating streamflow quantities.  I have the source code for SWAT, it's written in fortran.  I'm basically asking how to talk with SWAT using my python code.  SWAT uses txt files to compile the watershed model.  I need to intercept SWATs writting of txt files with my simulated land use rasters...over and over again for each yearly change of land use.  I don't know where to start so any advice on the process would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Does SWAT simply read in files from the disk for its input?

Comment: When you say 'intercept', would monitoring a drop file location suffice, or is more direct interaction required?

Comment: SWAT creates the input files from a topographical map, land use map and soil map.  I can first create the files for a "base" case, but I need to re-write the files having to do with land use for each change I make.

Comment: I second the suggestion to try f2py to call SWAT directly from Python. However, if that doesn't solve it for you, I'd suggest asking on the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) as well, as this is pretty close to being a GIS problem, you might find people with SWAT experience there.

Comment: Perhaps I just need some sleep, but I'm having trouble forming a mental picture of the workflow/flow of information. Do you need to repeatedly call the SWAT model, each time modifying the output data and use it as the input for the next run, or do you call SWAT once and need to alter the files it uses while it is running? If the latter, I fear it may require quite some work on SWAT's source code, if it doesn't already have an interface for doing this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the leads...didn't know there was a GIS Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWAT is probably written to run non-interactively (in "batch" mode). If it generates lots and lots of files with a single call, your program can read them in and process them. If it needs to be called a lot of times to generate your results, you can call SWAT from your python program. Figure out how the command line options (or control file) that SWAT needs, then take a look at the python module `subprocess`.

Comment: Just an update on how I handled this...Alexis gave the best lead by just simply opening the SWAT model from my code using the subprocess module.  At the time, I didn't know this existed.  I can complete some very complicated steps in the watershed model with a few clicks of a mouse instead of trying to get too involved the watershed models subroutines.  There's about 50-60 subroutines associated with it.  I found just opening the model, doing my thing and closing it before the code moves on was the best solution for my case.  Thanks for you help Alexis.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [F2PY](http://www.scipy.org/F2py)?  If SWAT has already, or you could write yourself, a way to get the data before it's written to the file, you could make a fairly seamless interface.  (I did this type of things years ago for some legacy code and was super happy with the result.  It made working with the program and data much, much easier.)

Comment: No, I haven't looked into that.  Thanks for the lead.  I will try it.